# statistical modeling data modeling and algorithm modeling

Tags: regression, neural-networks, modeling

In modeling culture, there is statistical modeling and algorithm modeling. but I do not understand that why linear regression is data modeling and decision tree or Neural network is algorithm modeling. 
 
sice linear regression is try to find the unknown parameter and also NN does.

Comment: can you share the source where you saw the distinction?

Comment: Who gave you this nomenclature?